# How do I make a number increment counter a single point in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to increase the value of a number using the setInterval to repeat the execution.

```
var x = document.getElementById("text");

var y = setInterval(counter, 1000);

function counter() {

 var a = document.getElementById("number");

 x.innerHTML += a.value * 2;

}
```

var a is an input field while var x is a paragraph. When i click the counter button which invokes the function, the value in the paragraph does not change but begins to loop the same figure.

E.g, if the value present in the paragraph is 2, and the value in the input field is 2, my result would be a repeating "444444..." that extends continuously to the right. However, what I want is to make the single value increase by 4,8,16 on a single point like a normal counter would do.

Need assistance please. This also occurs when i use the for statement without `<br>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53y250vL/7/ This would first apply the number from the input field into the paragraph, then jump into the loop to multiply it by 2 in a loop.

Comment: Why is there a jQuery tag?

Answer (score 0):

Remove concatenation:

> x.innerHTML = a.value * 2;

instead of

> x.innerHTML += a.value * 2;

Comment: The value in x,innerHTML will not increase at all because the plus sign is as assignment operator to increase the value

Answer (score 0):

try

```
x.innerHTML = parseInt(x.innerHTML) + (parseInt(a.value) * 2);
```

Comment: The above resulted to NaN

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parseInt to convert into integer otherwise it will do a string concatenation.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("text");

var y = setInterval(counter, 1000);

function counter() {

 var a = document.getElementById("number");

 x.innerHTML = parseInt(x.innerHTML)+ a.value * 2;

}
```

Comment: @UchennaAjah: This answer doesn't give the desired result you show in your question.

Comment: I am actually putting each code to test immediately they are placed here and the answer did exactly what i want @ Crazy Train.  The problem now is that i changed the value "2" into 0.02 and it stopped working repeatedly, just once.

Comment: if you want decimal numbers then use parseFloat

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/53y250vL/7/

This would first apply the number from the input field into the paragraph, then jump into the loop to multiply it by 2 in a loop.

```
<input id="number" />

<p id="text">

</p>

<button id="counterButton">
Count
</button>
```

---

```
var x = document.getElementById("text");
function counter() {

    x.innerHTML = parseInt(x.innerHTML) * 2;

}


document.getElementById("counterButton").addEventListener('click', function() {

var a = document.getElementById("number");
x.innerHTML = a.value;

var y = setInterval(counter, 1000);
}, false);
```